# Are there any hidden settings to modify default system sleep conditions?

Tags: macos, power-management

Is it possible in some way to modify conditions when OS X will go to sleep? 
In my opinion the time delay of system sleep is insufficient.

Imagine the situation that we are in the middle of downloading some large file over http, after leaving MBP for e.g. 4 min cause a system sleep therefore all tcp connections will be broken. It is not only anoying.

The caffeinate command can be used but it will implicit prevent OS X from sleeping.

Does anyone have cure for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications that download files should create a power assertion to prevent idle sleep. But for ones that don't, you can add something like this to the crontab (`EDITOR=nano crontab -e`):

```
* * * * * pgrep -x uTorrent && caffeinate -t 60
```

You haven't missed the energy saver settings, right?

[image]

Comment: Very nice walk-around :)